# GWT : How to prevent client-side state from being cleared when a redirection (for e.g : OAuth2) happens?

Tags: gwt, oauth-2.0, client-side, state, gwt2

I am implementing OAuth2 authentication for one of my GWT projects (let's call it *GWT-app*). The application responsible for authentication is a third-party application based on *Spring Framework-3.1.2.RELEASE* and uses its OAuth2 implementation included in *Spring Security-3.1.3.RELEASE* (let's call it *OAuth-app*).

*GWT-app* is a management application for **managing user and stores**. Each user has *one or more manager accounts*. A *manager account* may have *one or more stores attached* to it so that he can manage them altogether from one screen of the *GWT-app*.

It means that the user **may potentially have to authenticate many times** through different *manager accounts* to display stores by manager account on the app.

So on the **StoreManagement.java** page of my *GWT-app*, I have the following :

```
private final Map<String, ManagerAndStoresProxy> managerAndStores = Maps.newTreeMap(Ordering.natural());
```

after authentication, this map should be populated with Manager name and a List of attached stores for each.

**OAUTH2 FLOW**

The *Authorization-code* flow is used for authentication. When *GWT-app* wants to authenticate someone, it redirects the user to a login page on *OAuth-app*. The user enters his credentials and will be presented with an authorization page asking him whether he wants to allow *GWT-app to access his information*. If the user clicks on authorize, he is redirected back to the GWT-app with an access token.

**THE PROBLEM**

The only issue is that since *GWT-app* is redirecting the user to another application for authentication, the first time the authentication works and the map is populated correctly but if I have to authenticate another account then the previously authenticated account is **cleared and can not be retrieved** because of the redirection.

The question is then : how can I proceed **to persist** this map and retrieve it back when a second (third, fourth and so on) authentication flow is over (i.e after the url-redirection of OAuth-app).

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED SO FAR**

What I did so far is that when the user wants to proceed with authentication from the **StoreManagement.java** page, he is presented with a *popup* redirected to the *OAuth-app* authentication page. The **access token** is then retrieved from this popup but I have to send it back to the parent window (i.e StoreManagement.java page). This can be done via a HTTP GET parameter but this method **reloads** the **parent page** and the result is the same: the previously authenticated account is cleared.

**QUESTION**

What is the best way to handle this situation without clearing the previous context and without requiring any server-side session mechanism whatsoever ?

Comment: Could you tell me what library do you use for client-side oauth2 authentication?

Answer (score 1):

The root of the problem is using the authorization code grant; the implicit grant (aka client-side flow) would be a much better fit.

Comment: you are right : I have checked the IETF-OAuth2 draft and saw that implicit grant is a good option for clients implemented in browsers. C.f [IETF OAuth2 Draft : Implicit flow](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-31#section-1.3.2)

Comment: Or the more approachable overview by Google: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent

Answer (score 0):

If your app is not limited by old browsers in terms of compatibility then you can try to store all necessary things in [HTML5 Web Storage](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideHtml5Storage.html).

Comment: > but that's a problem since we DO have old browsers unfortunately :) ...We would like to solve this issue in a more gwt-fashion, if possible of course.

Comment: I can't see all complexity behind `ManagerAndStoresProxy`, but maybe you can serialize it and store using coockies?

Comment: Maksym > the structure is quite complex and therefore it may have an impact on the size of the cookie when serializing but thanks that would have been an option if the data were a little simpler in terms of structure. Thomas (below) pointed out that the authorization flow I am using is the problem and after reading the IETF-OAuth2 draft [here](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-31#section-1.3.2)  he's right so maybe I will give it a try just to see whether it may work or not.